# Optimize mySQL query - Update JOIN 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have 1 big table "A" (millions of rows) and I would like to update one column based on the data of another "small" table "B" only if "pack_id" from TableA is = as "hello".

This is my query:

```
    UPDATE tableA JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT tableB.destino, tableB.estado from table2) as tableB ON tableA.email = tableB.destino
    SET tablaA.estado = tableB.estado
    WHERE tableA.pack_id = "hello";
```

This query takes a very long time.
So much that sometimes it is not even able to finish.

Is there any way to optimize this query?

Thank you.

Comment: If you could try adding the index, I think that would help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you avoid the `SELECT DISTINCT`?

```
UPDATE tableA a JOIN
       tableB b
       ON a.email = b.destino
    SET a.estado = b.estado
    WHERE a.pack_id = 'hello';
```

Then for this query, you want indexes on `a(pack_id, email)` and `b(destino)`.